# Firefox 9.0 loads Apps tab despite preference not to load tabs

Tags: firefox

I upgraded Firefox from 8.0 to 9.0 then 9.0.1 with regular updates

IIRC 8.0 version did not reload any tabs if set in General preferences, and 9.0 does not reload regular tabs but reloads Apps tabs

Did someone else notice this?
I'm I right that 8.0 startup time was immediate while 9.0 needs more time to become fully accessible because of reloading Apps tabs? If yes is there setting to tell not to reload Apps tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this on Firefox 9, 10, 11 and 12. On Firefox 8 pinned tabs are not loaded. I recommend taking a look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org to see if anyone else already reported this and to create a new bug report. It could be the intention of the devs to automatically load pinned tabs, but it could also be a bug.

The only preferences I am aware of are **browser.sessionstore.restore_hidden_tabs** and **browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand**. The first controls tabs on hidden panorama groups, which means any group not currently in display. The second one controls the tabs on the active group.

**Bug:**

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708585

**Related bugs:**

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688962

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674452

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. **browser.sessionstore.restore_hidden_tabs** is already set to `false` so I guess there is no other possible setting. About bug report: that bugzilla seems too advanced for me, if someone feels like doing it, please...

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the bugs related to this issue. Essentially, they did that on purpose and they are now adding a new pref to control pinned tabs. The pref will be browser.sessionstore.restore_pinned_tabs.